# Open Source replacement for WPML?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, translation, plugin-wpml

Since WPML is not free anymore and still one of the most used Wordpress Translation Plugins, is there an open source project that keeps development going? Or something similar that replaces it?

I know there are other alternatives out there, but most have different approaches or features. I for example like the fact, that every translation is in it's own post.

Comment: forgive me for asking, but what I don't understand is that when you like WPML so much, why not just pay the license fee and be done with it?

Comment: We are a translation agency and we would like to include our own translation API into an existing plugin. With the commercial version of WPML this is not possible.

Comment: Let's put is this way: WPML.org is ripping of it's users, asking for a **anual** fee of **79$**, so I am looking for an open source replacement, other that I could switch to with minimal effort and one that is it not going commercial.

Comment: @SorinSbarnea why don't you roll your own then?

Comment: @Sorin Sbarnea that is utterly ridiculous , first off WPLM is open source. Secondly 79$ is a nominal fee to pay for such a well written and comprehensive plugin. Go ahead and write your own and get back to us in 5 years with what you can accomplish. As a real developer WPML has saved me and my clients tens of thousands of $

Comment: Is the paid version still open source? Meaning, I pay to download it or how does it work?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed, as I think it is natural to search for alternatives. Perfect answer would be listing with all known alternatives. I found pretty good comparison of those: http://www.wpmayor.com/wordpress-translation-plugins-part-3-alternatives-wpml/

Comment: RTFM! :-) See the official WordPress codex:https://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress. It lists WPGlobus, Polylang, qTranslate, xili-language and Sublanguage as recommended plugins and they're all free.

Answer (score 5):

Try [qtranslate](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/)...I use it religiously. Has some issues like with dates and times, but I always find a solution.

Comment: Thank you dew. I've looked at it, but don't really like the way it stores all translations into the same post.

Answer (score 4):

[Polylang](http://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) seems to be a direct alternative to WPML.

From the plugin description:

> Polylang allows you to create a bilingual or multilingual WordPress
>   site. You write posts, pages and create categories and post tags as
>   usual, and then define the language for each of them. The translation
>   of a post, whether it is in the default language or not, is optional.

It even can import WPML settings with the [WPML to Polylang](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpml-to-polylang/) plugin

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution being developed at the moment:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multilingual-press/

Looks pretty good, but haven't tried it out yet.